# Customize Data Studio reports with different filters for different users

Tags: filter, user-controls, customization, looker-studio

I have many end users for my reports. Some of them want to look at all website data, some just section A, some section B, etc. For my own sanity and not having to create the same report over and over with different filters, I'm wondering if there's either:

1. A way to provide a link to a report where the link tells data studio what filter to apply to the report
2. A way to filter the report based on the user who's logging in.

I have the impression that neither of these is possible, and it seems like people are reluctant to have one dashboard that they have to proactively filter for their section (I'm still going to try that). But I'm hoping that there's perhaps something I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is possible using Custom bookmark links ([doc](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7664330)). The Drill down table example ([doc](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7678010)) shows how you can create a table with records linking to a second page of the dashboard with different filters. You could use this to create filter pre-sets for different users groups.
2. This is currently not possible.